What's wrong with my counter-example to an exercise in Tapp's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces?
Exercise 1.23 in Tapp's Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces asks: "Let $\gamma : I \to \mathbb R^3$ be a regular space curve, and let $P \subset \mathbb R^3$ be a plane that does not intersect the image of $\gamma$. If $\gamma$ comes closest to $P$ at time $t_0$, prove that $\gamma'(t_0)$ is parallel to $P$.
This immediately seemed strange to me as I imagined $\gamma$ as a straight line perpendicular to $P$. So, for example, consider the curve $\gamma(t) = (t, 0, 0)$ where $I = [0, 1]$, and consider the plane $P = (2, p_y, p_z)$, so that $P$ is a plane extending over $x = 2$. Then the image of $\gamma$ never intersects $P$ as we never have $t = 2$ for values of $t$ in $I = [0, 1]$. Further, $\gamma'(t) = (1, 0, 0)$, so that $\gamma'(t_0) = (1, 0, 0)$. Then considering two arbitrary points in $P$, $P_0 = (2, y_0, z_0)$ and $P_1 = (2, y_1, z_1)$, and the vector between them $\mathbf r = (0, y_0 - y_1, z_0 - z_1)$, we have that $\langle \gamma'(t_0), \mathbf r \rangle = 1 \times 0 + 0 \times (y_0 - y_1) - 0 \times (z_0 - z_1) = 0$, so that $\gamma'(t_0)$ and $\mathbf r$ are orthogonal to each other. Therefore $\gamma'(t_0)$ is orthogonal to any vector lying in $P$, and therefore $\gamma'(t_0)$ is orthogonal to $P$, not parallel.
Where am I misunderstanding?

Your counter-example seems fine to me. Perhaps the exercise could be fixed by requiring that $I$ is open? Or, equivalently, that $t_0$ is not on the endpoints of $I$?

I think, he implicitly assumes that $t_0$ is an interior point of $I$, otherwise, the claim is simply false. Things like this do happen, get used to it.

Interesting, thank you. I'll try to re-think the problem with this extra stipulation in mind. The first definition in the book he simply says that $I$ is a nonempty connected subset of $\mathbb R$, and even explicitly includes $I$ having closed endpoints, so it's a bit odd.

Does the term "regular space curve" include some restrictions on $I$?

"Regular" is in Definition 1.9 as $|\gamma'(t)| \neq 0$ for all $t \in I$. A "space curve" is defined in Example 1.3 as "a curve in $\mathbb R^3$", so a smooth function $I \to \mathbb R^3$. Example 1.3 is called a "space curve" where $t \in (-\infty, \infty)$, but Exercise 1.13 gives a "space curve" with $t \in [0, 2\pi]$. So no I don't think it does include restrictions on $I$.

My experience on this site the last few years suggests that there are more than a few errors in this lovely book. The first few times I communicated them to the author, but no more … :) You should solve the problem as Moishe suggested. By the way, in your counterexample, do you actually need the line segment to be orthogonal to the plane?
